# multiple command in postStart hook of a container

Tags: kubernetes

in a kubernetes Deployment yaml file is there a simple way to run multiple commands in the postStart hook of a container?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
lifecycle:
  postStart:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/cp", "/webapps/myapp.war", "/apps/"]
      command: ["/bin/mkdir", "-p", "/conf/myapp"]
      command: ["touch", "/conf/myapp/ready.txt"]
```

But it doesn't work.
(looks like only the last command is executed)

I know I could embed a script in the container image and simply call it there... But I would like to be able to customize those commands in the yaml file without touching the container image.

thanks

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Only one `command` allowed, but you can use `sh -c` like this

```
  lifecycle:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command:
          - "sh"
          - "-c"
          - >
            if [ -s /var/www/mybb/inc/config.php ]; then
            rm -rf /var/www/mybb/install;
            fi;
            if [ ! -f /var/www/mybb/index.php ]; then
            cp -rp /originroot/var/www/mybb/. /var/www/mybb/;
            fi
```

Comment: I am not able to edit but for concatenating multiple commands is necessary to add the concatenations "&&" at the end of each line. Using `|` instead of `>` avoids to adding bash concatenations

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: @AlexDeiwor do you know why my code is changing from - | to -> and the code is not exactly as I wrote it (spaces, incidents), this is not happening in my probe code...

Comment: /bin/sh instead of sh -c worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You also can create a bash or make script to group all those commands.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

command_one
command_two
command_three
```

Comment: Can you give an example ?